# Updating existing fields in MS Access database through classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I've been given working ASP code which I have to change in order to update existing data in database insted of creating new entries. I think I should swap INSERT INTO statment with UPDATE but the code is a bit too coplicated for me to figure out where and what to change. 
Here it comes:

```
// *** Edit Operations: declare variables

// set the form action variable
var MM_editAction = Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME");
if (Request.QueryString) {
MM_editAction += "?" + Server.HTMLEncode(Request.QueryString);
}

// boolean to abort record edit
var MM_abortEdit = false;


// query string to execute
var MM_editQuery = "";

// *** Insert Record: set variables

if (String(Request("MM_insert")) == "AddRecord") {

  var MM_editConnection = MM_PhoneWeb_conn_STRING;
  var MM_editTable  = "Employees";
  var MM_editRedirectUrl = "userRegister.asp";
  var MM_fieldsStr =     "textSurname|value|textFirstname|value|textUsername|value|textPass|value";
  var MM_columnsStr =     "Surname|',none,''|FirstName|',none,''|Username|',none,''|Password|',none,''";

  // create the MM_fields and MM_columns arrays
  var MM_fields = MM_fieldsStr.split("|");
  var MM_columns = MM_columnsStr.split("|");

  // set the form values
  for (var i=0; i+1 < MM_fields.length; i+=2) {
    MM_fields[i+1] = String(Request.Form(MM_fields[i]));
  }

  // append the query string to the redirect URL
  if (MM_editRedirectUrl && Request.QueryString && Request.QueryString.Count > 0) {
    MM_editRedirectUrl += ((MM_editRedirectUrl.indexOf('?') == -1)?"?":"&") +     Request.QueryString;
  }
}

// *** Insert Record: construct a sql insert statement and execute it

if (String(Request("MM_insert")) != "undefined") {

  // create the sql insert statement
  var MM_tableValues = "", MM_dbValues = "";
  for (var i=0; i+1 < MM_fields.length; i+=2) {
    var formVal = MM_fields[i+1];
    var MM_typesArray = MM_columns[i+1].split(",");
    var delim =    (MM_typesArray[0] != "none") ? MM_typesArray[0] : "";
    var altVal =   (MM_typesArray[1] != "none") ? MM_typesArray[1] : "";
    var emptyVal = (MM_typesArray[2] != "none") ? MM_typesArray[2] : "";
    if (formVal == "" || formVal == "undefined") {
      formVal = emptyVal;
    } else {
      if (altVal != "") {
        formVal = altVal;
      } else if (delim == "'") { // escape quotes
        formVal = "'" + formVal.replace(/'/g,"''") + "'";
      } else {
        formVal = delim + formVal + delim;
      }
    }
    MM_tableValues += ((i != 0) ? "," : "") + MM_columns[i];
    MM_dbValues += ((i != 0) ? "," : "") + formVal;
  }
  MM_editQuery = "insert into " + MM_editTable + " (" + MM_tableValues + ") values (" +     MM_dbValues + ")";


  if (!MM_abortEdit) {
    // execute the insert

    var MM_editCmd = Server.CreateObject('ADODB.Command');
    MM_editCmd.ActiveConnection = MM_editConnection;
    MM_editCmd.CommandText = MM_editQuery;
    MM_editCmd.Execute();
    MM_editCmd.ActiveConnection.Close();

    if (MM_editRedirectUrl) {
      Response.Redirect(MM_editRedirectUrl);
```

Comment: That code looks probably vulnerable to an SQL injection attack. I would suggest you report back stating it is insecure, and rewriting it from scratch.

Comment: @tomfanning, code is about 10 years old and will be used for the internal website with up to 15 users. No important data will be stored in the database. I'd rather finish it as it is.

Comment: That looks like C#, not Classic ASP.

Comment: @Remou this is JScript, auto generated by DreamWeaver. Can't be any worse!

Comment: Yup, I just got DreamWeaver installed but it looks horrible. Any ideas how can I get it working without writing whole website from the scratch?

Comment: Well, we need more details. Update based on what field? What is your key field? If such record does not exist, ignore or insert new record?

Comment: By the way when replying to comments please use `@` e.g. @Shadow to notify the other user of your comment.